# Getting Pandas dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe: 
[image]

Let's say I have `id` = 16 and want the `search_term` associated with it. How would I extract that?

Comment: `df[df['id']==16]['search_term']`

Comment: Do a bit more research yourself before throwing your problems here. Some reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: I think better is use plain text for your sample as image, because coders cannot copy image as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print df
   id  product_id   product_title     search_term  relevance
0   2      100001  Simpsom Strong    anglebracket       3.00
1   3      100001  Simpsom Strong        ibracket       2.50
2  16      100005      Delta Vero  rainshowerhead       2.33
```

```
df = df.ix[df['id']==16, 'search_term']
print df
2    rainshowerhead
Name: search_term, dtype: object
```

```
df = df.loc[df['id']==16, 'search_term']
print df
2    rainshowerhead
Name: search_term, dtype: object
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - last paragraph (`In [126]`).

Or you can use [Gustavo Bezerra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678889/getting-pandas-dataframe-value#comment59036180_35678889) solution from comment:

```
df[df['id']==16]['search_term']
```